# How to read XML file into Sagemaker Notebook Instance?

Tags: python, xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I have files in `XML format` saved in `S3 bucket` and I want to parse them with `xml.etree` inside a `Sagemaker's Notebook` Instance. I tried the following but it produces `FileNotFoundError`:

```
data_location = `s3://data-bucket/1.xml`
xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(data_location)
```

Comment: So your question is *"How to read data from `s3://` URLs in Python?"*

Comment: No, my question is how to parse XML files in Sagemaker notebook from file location in S3.

Comment: No, that's not your question. Try the solution in the duplicate I linked to. Parsing the XML is not the problem here.

Comment: ...or to put it differently, `s3://` is not a form of URL that Python can read without help from some sort of library. Once you have that in place, parsing the XML will work as you would expect it.